# Windows long term version

Tags: windows-10

Currently, we have 3 versions of Windows 10 that get long-term support: 1809    Long-Term Servicing Channel (LTSC), 1607 Long-Term Servicing Branch (LTSB), and 1507 Long-Term Servicing Branch (LTSB). Is there is a way to define whether my Windows 10 version is a long term without hardcoding these values? I mean at some point we might have a new Windows 10 LTSC and I need a reliable way to detect it in my program code.

We can identify the OS version running the following code in PowerShell `[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version`. But the version I get doesn't tell me if this is a long-term support version or not. I wish we have something like `[System.Environment]::OSVersion.IsLTS`. But do we have a workaround here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API called [GetProductInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo) that can be also [called from .net](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getproductinfo), which returns `PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S` for LTSB versions.

Comment: What if I need LTSC version, is it still will be PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_S?

Comment: this is both the same, only name was changed